# Autofac IAsyncDisposable support during regular lifetime scopes

Tags: c#, autofac

I was wondering how Autofac handles IAsyncDisposable with the regular lifetimes.

Let's say we have a component registered via

```
builder.RegisterType<DnsResolutionService>()
    .As<IDnsResolutionService>()
    .SingleInstance();
```

While reading the docs I found the following:

> While you do not have to implement IDisposable if you implement IAsyncDisposable, we strongly recommend you do so. If your component only implements IAsyncDisposable, but someone disposes of the scope synchronously, then Autofac will throw an exception, because it does not know how to dispose of your component.

I'm a bit confused now, and essentially I have two questions in my head:

1. Do the regular lifetime scopes added to a registration fully support async disposing? Or does a synchronous disposal only happen if I explicitly use something like `using(var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())` - Which I actually basically never use due to only using constructor injection.
2. In case something would actually try to dispose my component, which would implement both `IDisposable` and `IAsyncDisposable`, as the docs suggest, in a synchronous way, then it will probably only call IDisposable. In this case, do I have to dispose all my IAsyncDisposables in the synchronous dispose block as well? Does Autofac provide any kind of order, e.g. IAsyncDisposable is called first, so I can maybe keep track of what's already disposed and what isn't? Or do I have to manage this myself?

Comment: Seems like it'd be an easy unit test to hook up to find the answer. Have you tried it?

Comment: If its single instance - does it really matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to answer your questions, but there's a 'depends' in there, just to warn you.

1. All the lifetime scopes fully support asynchronous disposal. If you are using the ASP.NET Core integration, then lifetime per-request scopes will always be automatically disposed of using the `DisposeAsync` method.  However if you create a lifetime scope some other way, you will need to use `await using` yourself to make it dispose asynchronously.
2. This one depends on how you are consuming those resources you need to clean up.

   If your component takes dependencies on services injected by Autofac, and those services are **not** [ExternallyOwned](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/disposal.html?highlight=externallyowned#disabling-disposal), then don't dispose of them yourself, let Autofac take care of that for you. Autofac knows to invoke the synchronous `Dispose` on a component if the scope is being disposed asynchronously, but the component doesn't implement `IAsyncDisposable`.

   If you are injecting `ExternallyOwned` components, or allocating resources inside your component that Autofac doesn't know about, you will need to dispose of those yourself, either using `Dispose` or `DisposeAsync` as required, in the normal way.